# Nginx - IP server in url works, domain not, how I solve this?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, domain, vps

I am hosting a React web app on a VPS server and im using Nginx to host the React. While I can access the website via the IP in the browser's URL, it doesn't work when using the domainexample.app.

My VPS is running Ubuntu. Accessing my site using the IP address in the URL poses no issues. However, attempting to access it through the domain (e.g., mysite.app) proves timeout error. The domain has been purchased, and the DNS is properly configured. When testing with 'ping mysite.app' in the command prompt, the server's IP is correctly displayed, and the same holds true for the 'curl' command. The issue seems to specifically arise when trying to access it through the browser.

The nginx.conf file is already configured (I believe correctly), along with the server_name configuration file in the sites-available folder.

File nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes auto; pid /run/nginx.pid; include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events { worker_connections 768; }

http { 

include /etc/nginx/mime.types; default_type application/octet-stream;

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
types_hash_max_size 2048;


#ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

gzip on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

File in sites-available:

```
server { 
listen 80; root /var/www/html/exemplopasta/exemplopasta/build; 
server_name dominioexemplo.app;

location / { 
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}

location /login {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}

location /register {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}

location /dashboard {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}

location /aboutus { 
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}

location /forgotpassword {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}

location /error {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
} 
}
```

What i already tried:

```
I've already linked the 'mysite.app' file from 'sites-available' to 'sites-enabled' using the command: ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

The DNS is redirecting to my server IP, as I mentioned; 'curl' and 'ping' are responding with an 'OK'.

There are no errors in the nginxlog, and the server access logs only register when the user uses the IP in the URL.

Browsers show a timeout error after a few seconds when I try to access 'mydomain.app'.

When I search 'mydomain.app' on Google, it shows my website, even with the summary site, indicating that my domain.app has access to the site data.
```

My main objective here is to be able to access my website via domain, and not only by using the IP address.

Im having this problem for more than one month now, does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

**EDIT**
I found the problem. My problem was happening beacuse i bought a .app domain, and .app domain is a secure domain, so it only accepts HTTPS.

Comment: Can you please run `nginx -T`. And restart nginx

Comment: Crossdupes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258202/how-does-google-force-https-on-their-app-tld https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357350/browsers-force-https-for-my-nginx-server-serving-a-app-domain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031374/unable-to-connect-my-dns-with-app-extension-to-my-apache-server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392130/cant-link-domain-name-to-ip-nothing-displays and more.

Answer (score 0):

This was to long for a comment, but please also enable logs your in your vhost

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
root /var/www/html/exemplopasta/exemplopasta/build; 
    server_name dominioexemplo.app;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log combined;
    
    # Define the error log file and its log level
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log error;

    location / { 
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    }
    
    location /login {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    }
    
    location /register {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    }
    
    location /dashboard {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    }
    
    location /aboutus { 
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    }
    
    location /forgotpassword {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    }
    
    location /error {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    } 
    }
```

Comment: I added the error and the access logs, just like you said. But nothing happend. 
When i do tail -f to watch the access/error logs, i only receive something when i try to access my webapp with the http://SERVERIP.app, but when i try with the http://mydomain.app, nothing happend and i receive a timeout error in the browser.